# getting local json data to android with ionic 3

Tags: android, json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I already googled the problem and found several solutions for it. But most of them are for ionic 2 and angular 2. I don't know if there are any changes for angular 5 and ionic 3, which i'm using.

I'm having a local json file and i'm getting my data from it. In the browser it works totally fine but on my android tablet my data isn't shown.

The solutions I found were mostly about a path problem. Most of them said to change the path for android like this:

**service.ts**

```
  loadData() {   
  var url = 'assets/data/skills.json';
  if (this.platform.is('cordova') && this.platform.is('android')) {
          url = "/android_asset/www/" + url;
      }
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(url)
        .subscribe((data) => {
          resolve(data);
        }, err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

Path of service.ts:

> Project/src/providers/service/service.ts

The path of my json file:

> Project/src/assets/data/skills.json

Looking at my research, I assume the path of the json file for android deplyoment has to be something like this:

> Project/android_asset/www/assets/data/skills.json

But the folder "android_asset" doesn't even exist in my project, but most of the research said, that it should be there. Or was this probably only in an older angular/ionic version?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48162962/4826457

Comment: @SurajRao This is bascially the code I'm already having, but this still won't work

Comment: I would suggest trying with a url similar to the link and not the whole Project/android_asset/..

Comment: @SurajRao When you look at my code, I don't use the whole path. I use relative paths. I just wrote the whole paths in my question for clarity, where my files are.

Comment: Also another typo you have string `'url'` instead of variable here: `this.http.get('url')`

Comment: @SurajRao Oh, thanks I didn't see this typo. I corrected it but sadly it still won't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To access your assets in your `.html`, `.scss` and `.ts` files, you can start by using:

```
./assets/[YOUR PATH]
```

`./` will let you reference your files, starting in the `src` folder!

Answer (score 0):

Those who are still looking for solution for ios, android and browser, here is the approach which worked for me:

```
var url = ""; 
    if(this.platform.is('core') || this.platform.is('mobileweb')) {
      url = 'assets/data/localfile.json'; 
    }else{
      if(this.platform.is('android')){
        url = "/android_asset/www/assets/data/localfile.json";
      }else if(this.platform.is('ios')){
        url = 'assets/data/localfile.json'; 
      }
    }
    return this.http.get(url)
    .map((res:Response) => res.json());
```

And add this line in config.xml:-

```
<allow-navigation href="http://localhost/*" />
```